# Woes installing PIL

Tags: software-installation, pip

I get this error when I try to run my program.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "green.py", line 11, in 
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL

I already tried "pip install PIL" and "sudo pip install PIL" which give me the error: 
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module that you need is `pillow`.

Depending on the `Python` version for which you want to install it and the version of `pip`, one of the following will work:

```
pip install pillow

pip3 install pillow
```

After that, you can import `PIL`

To give an explanation of why `pillow` is needed and not `PIL`, the former is a fork of the latter. The last release of `PIL` was in 2009 when it was forked off into `Pillow`. The acronym stands for `Python Image Library` and it is used for opening, manipulating, and saving image formats. It explains the `Image ImportError` in your question.

Comment: I had to lookup pillow to find out it is a fork of PIL. The answer could benefit from explaining what it is, and why it is needed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro So did I. I'll add the explanation later on today.